# Problems with printing integers in C on Mac Terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal

When I print integers in C they end up next to the new command line in terminal. How do I stop that from happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("%d", 1200);
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like: 1200MacBook-Pro:File user$

Comment: `printf("%d", 1200);` --> `printf("%d\n", 1200);`

Comment: This behaviour is not specific to Macs; it will apply to pretty much any Unix-based machine, and probably applies to Windows if you're in a command-line environment.  (It doesn't affect GUI applications, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Do the same thing you did with `Hello World!`: include a newline (`\n`) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
printf("%d", 1200);
```

to this:

```
printf("%d\n", 1200);
```

(Of course the `MacBook-Pro:File user$` is not part of your program's output.)